# How to count possibilities in python lists

Tags: python

Given a list like this:

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

There are 10 three-element combinations:

```
[123, 124, 125, 134, 135, 145, 234, 235, 245, 345]
```

How can I generate this list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools

num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
combinations = []
for combination in itertools.combinations(num, 3):
    combinations.append(int("".join(str(i) for i in combination)))
# => [123, 124, 125, 134, 135, 145, 234, 235, 245, 345]
print len(combinations)
# => 10
```

**Edit**

You can skip int(), join(), and str() if you are only interested in the number of combinations. itertools.combinations() gives you tuples that may be good enough.

Comment: If the OP only wants to know the number of combinations, then actually generating all of them is not the most efficient way to go about. </understatement>

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. Thank you.
python is very powerful.

btw, if I want to do the same thing in C++, Does it have a easy way to do so?

Comment: Sorry, my C++ is ten years old :)

Comment: @okman: The code for `itertools.combinations` is in the docs http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations  So you may be able to adapt it to C++.  Or google around for "c++ permutations combinations".

Comment: C++ doesn't have a direct equivalent in the standard library. next_permutation comes pretty close but you still need to do some extra work. If performance isn't an issue then you can generate all permutations of 5 digits, discard the 2 trailing digits in each case, and then discard any duplicate entries.


. (eg. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) For combinations rather than all permutations

Answer (score 5):

You are talking about [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). There are *n!/(k! * (n - k)!)* ways to take *k* elements from a list of *n* elements. So:

```
>>> num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> fac = lambda n: 1 if n < 2 else n * fac(n - 1)
>>> combos = lambda n, k: fac(n) / fac(k) / fac(n - k)
>>> combos(len(num), 3)
10
```

Use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) only if you actually want to generate all combinations. *Not* if you just want to know the *number* of different combinations.

Also, there are more efficient ways to calculate the number of combinations than using the code shown above. For example,

```
>>> from operator import truediv, mul
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> combos = lambda n, k: reduce(mul, starmap(truediv, zip(range(n, n - k, -1), range(k, 0, -1))))
>>> combos(len(num), 3)
10.0
```

(Note that this code uses floating point division!)

Comment: Still wrong.  If I want to take 2 items from [1, 1, 2], there should be two distinct combinations.

Comment: @recursive: you're right. I removed the remark (for now), because right now I am not able to figure out how the number of distinct combinations *should* be calculated.

Comment: Just change len(num) to len(set(num)), no?

Comment: @Alec: that's what I initially wrote, yes, but it is incorrect (as recursive's example shows).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.

```
>>> num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [i for i in itertools.combinations(num,3)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5),
 (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
>>>
```